# ImportError: cannot import name (unknown location)

Tags: python, distutils

## The project structure

```
my_package
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_module.py
└── setup.py
```

The module `my_module.py` has a single `func` function I am attempting to import.

The `setup.py` file has the following content.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_package',
    packages=find_packages(where='my_package'),
    version='1.0'
)
```

## The import API

I'm installing the package with:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 venv
source venv/bin/activate
python my_package/setup.py install
```

To then import it with:

```py
import my_package
from my_package import my_module
```

However, the second import fails with:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'my_module' from 'my_package' (unknown location)
```

Further more, running `dir(my_package)` reveals that indeed the `my_module` name did not get imported.
`['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

## Similar questions on SO

[setup.py installed package can't be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289017/setup-py-installed-package-cant-be-imported) provided solution proved non sucessfull.

[ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial' from 'serial' (unknown location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034429/importerror-cannot-import-name-serial-from-serial-unknown-location) adding a `__init__.py` file in `my_package/my_package` didn't work.

## Git repo

I've placed an example of the issue at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/prodrigues1990/import-setup/-/jobs/718813294)

Comment: To be clear, did you try also adding a `__init__.py` in `my_package/my_package`? Perhaps with contents `import .my_module`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Yes. I've updated the last phrase in th question. The `__init__.py` was placed in `my_package/my_package`. Adding the import you just said, didnt' work either.

Comment: From which (directory) location do you run the script (or Python prompt) that uses `from my_package import my_module`?

Comment: @00 check https://gitlab.com/prodrigues1990/import-setup/-/jobs/718813294 see if it answers your question

Comment: You can also look in `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/my_package` to see if `my_module.py` is there.

Comment: @00 at that location there is a `.egg` file `my_package-1.0-py3.8.egg`

Comment: The gitlab build/job/ci link may go away. You should include the relevant information (i.e., the actual answer to my question) in your question, so the question stands on its own (and my answer also makes a bit more sense to other readers).

Comment: @00 from the directory one level above `setup.py`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running your `test.py` script in the parent directory of your `my_package` directory. As a result, `test.py` will try and import the `my_package` subdirectory as a package/module, not your installed package. You will need to move to a directory that doesn't contain your source code and then run test. This could be as simply as running it inside a subdirectory `test` in the `my_package` main directory.
Just make sure you `cd` into that directory explicitly, instead of running it with a full path (like, for example, `python3.8 my_package/test/test.py`, because then it will still import the wrong `my_package`.

The reason for this (and cause of your problem) is that Python automatically includes the current working directory in your `sys.path`, at the start, and will thus try and import the main `my_package` directory as a package.