# ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from 'numpy' (unknown location)

Tags: visual-studio-code, window

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\ychen\Documents\GitHub\pollen_testing.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 3>()
1 import pandas as pd
2 import numpy as np
----> 3 from psy_strat.stratplot import stratplot
5 from IPython.display import Image
6 from overnight_consistency_checker import ConsistencyChecker, FFT_values

What is wrong with it, I do not know how to fix this problem. I even try to install numpy again, it does still not work out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name (unknown location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728242/importerror-cannot-import-name-unknown-location)